# Name for words with same consonant sounds but different vowel sounds

Tags: terminology, vowels, consonants

Is there a name for words with the same consonant sounds, but different vowel sounds?  For example:

- talk, take
- sit, site
- taught, tote
- bough, bow

My son has been mixing up these sets of words.  I'd like to find a list of them for him to practice (we homeschool him), but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: ***[Minimal Pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair)***. We say _talk_ and _take_ form a minimal pair for the vowels /ɔ/ and /e/. But it's not restricted to vowels. Any pair of words that differ in only one phoneme constitute a minimal pair, like _two_ and _do_, which form a minimal pair for /t/ and /d/.

Comment: For me, bow (qua bend down) has the same pronunciation as bough (qua tree part), so be careful with that one.  Also, note that record (as in record album) and record (as in make a recording) differ only in vowel sounds but are not minimal pairs, since two vowels sounds differ.

Comment: @Merk, I’m guessing he meant bough (tree part) vs. bow (weapon). I’ve certainly never heard of anyone using a [baʊ] and arrow. Also _record_ [noun] and _record_ [verb] also differ in stress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of literary analysis, there are a few applicable terms:

- Matching consonants create [**consonance.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_consonance)
- Words that nearly rhyme are [**half rhymes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_rhyme) or **slant rhymes.**
- Pairs where only the vowels vary are [**pararhymes.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pararhyme)

In the context of studying language, John Lawler's suggestion of [**minimal pair**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair) is apt: two words that differ in only a single sound that serves to distinguish them, sometimes subtly.

Comment: Then there's [_assonance_](http://wwwl.umich.edu/~jlawler/assonances.pdf) and [_rime_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/rimecoherence.pdf) in English, and _rime riche, rime pauvre,_ and _rime suffisante_ in French.